# Странные функции

Tags: c++

Я открыл файл с кодом на C++ и увидел там это:

```
void name ( void );
```

что это значит?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не видно попытки самому найти ответ

Comment: И как его можно закрыть?

Comment: И что я, по вашему мнению, должен был попытаться сделать?

Comment: Что вы должны делать - не знаю. Желающий чему-то научиться должен был набрать "(void) С++" в Google и получить ответ из первой же ссылки. Но подобная ваша, Вася, реакция говорит сама за себя. Обратите внимание на три минуса, которые получил вопрос. Вот упомянутая первая же ссылка из выдачи: <https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/void/#:~:text=In%20C%2C%20void%20is%20used,considered%20deprecated%20in%20C%2B%2B.>.

Answer (score 3):

Это объявление функции с именем `name`, которая не принимает и не возвращает параметров. Где-то дальше должно быть определение этой функции (может даже в другом файле).
Например вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void name(void);

int main()
{
    name();
    cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}

// здесь много какого-то кода
// ...

void name(void)
{
    cout << "\n";
}
```